# SimpleOnGestureListener.OnScroll isn't calling properly on fast scrolling

Tags: android

I need to change an image when the user swipes from left to right; that's why I have used `SimpleOnGestureListener` to detect a swipe event on an `ImageView`.

In this process, when I swipe an image slowly, the `onScroll()` method calls frequently and every thing is working fine but when I swipe this image fastly, the `onScroll()` method called hardly only two three times, please let me know what should I use to make the `onScroll()` method called according swipe's speed.

Comment: I think that's not a "scroll" , it's a "fling". You can try override that method.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I have also tried filling method but it does not calling as many times as onScroll method called

Comment: yes, then you can use `Scroller` to track the movement. Just search for an example of the tool.

Comment: now I am override onFling but it call only one time when initial motion event for scrolling. If you have any example of this then please send me, Thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of other ways of achieving what you want

[`onFling()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html#onFling%28android.view.MotionEvent,%20android.view.MotionEvent,%20float,%20float%29) gives you the velocity of `X` and `Y`: if it's greater than 4000 it counts as a fast scroll, then you can animate the continuous image, its effect like fast swiping.

Answer (score 3):

As there's much detail to say, I post my answer here rather than adding comments.

[`onFling`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener.html#onFling(android.view.MotionEvent,%20android.view.MotionEvent,%20float,%20float)) gives you four useful parameters : two `MotionEvent` and two velocity numbers. With these useful information you can call [`fling`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Scroller.html#fling(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) on a `Scroller`. The scroller object will do the rest work for you (e.g. get current x/y value after some time).

For your case, you could call `computeScrollOffset` and `getCurrX/getCurrY` to deal with your "swipe animation". Just change your showing image when the View's x/y reaches the boundary.

For instance , suppose your pointer up position is (0,0) and initial x velocity is 1000 pix/second. After 500 milliseconds, you call `computeScrollOffset` (it will return true certainly) and `getCurrX` might return 600 (because fling doesn't go linearly).The exact time to change the image is up to you.

For detail usage of `Scroller` there should be a lots of examples out there. One good example is certainly the [official training lession](http://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scroll.html)